# what's for referring to here? "for her presence of mind" in the lines mentioned below

Tags: meaning, prepositions

there's an article i was reading in newspaper and i stopped on this line beacause i couldn't been able to understand it properly,which says  "surender singh hooda said that if not for her presence of mind,jaswant would have not been arrested".
in this line 'for her presence' is used for what,instead it should be 'of her presence' i guess?
please explain!!
i'm very curious to know the meaning of this line.

Comment: Please use proper capitalization, punctuation, etc.

Comment: _For_ isn't referring to anything. _For_ here is part of the fixed phrase _if not for_, as @Bill points out.

Comment: It means: the arrest would not have been accomplished without her quick thinking.

Answer (score 2):

"If not for her presence of mind" is an alternative to saying

"If she didn't have presence of mind"

or

"If it weren't for her presence of mind".

"If not for" is a complex phrase, does that clear it up?

Comment: It's an idiomatic complex phrase, which makes it even more confusing. It's hard to tell what's been left out, so it's sort of fixed as three words introducing a Noun Phrase: _if not for `NP`_. You could think of it as a complex preposition, if that helps. The point is that it's fixed.